# How to get a subArray from Swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, swift2, sub-array

I keep trying to search for the proper way to get a sub array in Swift but I am missing something here. This code doesn't work because `rowArray.append(row)` throws an error that states.

> Cannot convert value of type 'ArraySlice<Int>' to specified type
>   '[Int]'

I can't figure out how to get an [Int] out of the main array or to convert ArraySlice<Int> to [Int]. I am guessing I am missing something simple but can't seem to find the answer from the docs.

```
var rowArray = [[Int]]()

var rangeStart = 0
let rangeLength = mapWidth

for var index = 0; index < mapHeight; ++index{
    rangeStart = tileIDs.count - ((index + 1) * mapWidth )

    let row : [Int] = tileIDs[rangeStart...rangeStart+rangeLength]
    rowArray.append(row)
}
rowArray.append(row)
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Convert `ArraySlice<Int>` to `[Int]` with `Array()`:

```
let row : [Int] = Array(tileIDs[rangeStart...rangeStart+rangeLength])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying so many different combinations and figured it was something simple.