# Swift Error: Cannot convert value of type 'ArraySlice' to expected argument type

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm getting this error and am new to Swift. I want to take the last 5 points of an array >= 5, and pass those 5 points as an array argument to a function. How can I achieve this and get past this error?

Cannot convert value of type 'ArraySlice' to expected argument type '[CGPoint]'

```
if (self.points?.count >= 5) {
    let lastFivePoints = self.points![(self.points!.count-5)..<self.points!.count]
    let angle = VectorCalculator.angleWithArrayOfPoints(lastFivePoints)
}
```

Comment: try `Array(yourArraySlice)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a subArray from Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060238/how-to-get-a-subarray-from-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to convert `ArraySlice` to `Array` using method `Array(Slice<Type>)`

```
if (self.points?.count >= 5) {
    let lastFivePoints = Array(self.points![(self.points!.count-5)..<self.points!.count])
    let angle = VectorCalculator.angleWithArrayOfPoints(lastFivePoints)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this negate the advantages of ArraySlice by instantiating a new Array; causing another allocation of memory.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the range operator you can use prefix(upTo end: Self.Index) method that return ArraySlice which makes your code shorter. Method's definition: The method returns a subsequence from the start of the collection up to, but not including, the specified position (index).

```
if (self.points?.count >= 5) {
  let lastFivePoints = Array<CGPoint>(self.points?.prefix(upTo:5)) as [AnyObject]
  let angle = VectorCalculator.angleWithArrayOfPoints(lastFivePoints)
}

// You can also do this 

let lastFivePoints = Array<CGPoint>(self.points?[0...4])
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried using `Array(lastFivePoints)` but i got error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

[image]

I ended up doing:

```
let arr = lastFivePoints.map({ (x) -> T in
                            return x
                        })
```

where T is the content class CGPoint for this example