# How to split json data into 2 different arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Currently we have an array which contains all the contents of the JSON Object:

```
  var castArray: [CastData] = []

    CastData.updateAllData(urlExtension: "\(movieID)/credits", completionHandler: { results in

      guard let results = results else {
        print("There was an error retrieving upcoming movie data")
        return
      }
      self.castArray = results
})
```

I'm trying to split the results of the JSON object into 2 arrays, the first 5 will go into the first array, the remainder will go into the 2nd array:

```
var first5CastArrayObjects: [CastData]
var theRestofTheCastArrayObjects: [CastData]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if castArray.count > 5 {
    let first5CastArrayObjects = castArray[0...4]
    var theRestofTheCastArrayObjects = castArray [5...castArray.count - 1]
} else {
    //Manage exception
}
```

Comment: There should be a range check to ensure the array has at least 6 values or this code will crash.

Comment: as rmaddy has said, you need something like `if castArray.count >= 5 { do this code} else print("array too small") return`

Comment: I tried this:   if castArray.count >= 5 {
      
        let first5CastArrayObjects = castArray[0...4]
        self.first5CastArray.append(first5CastArrayObjects)
    } but it throw the error:  Cannot convert value of type 'ArraySlice<CastData>' to expected argument type 'CastData'

Comment: try self.first5CastArray += first5CastArrayObjects if you want to append the new array to an existing one

Comment: @SwiftyJD check http://stackoverflow.com/a/35028887/5109911