# urlContentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")

Tags: ios, swift

In ,   urlContentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("")

I want to replace the "1" with a range of numbers.

When I write urlContentArray[1..")

I get this error message:

Value of type 'ArraySlice' has no member 'componentsSeparatedByString'

How can get I get range of numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060238/how-to-get-a-subarray-from-swift-2-0

Answer (score 0):

`urlContentArray` is an array. When you use `urlContentArray[1]` it returns a `String`.

So you can split by using `split` method as discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226940/swift-version-of-componentsseparatedbystring).

But when you do `urlContentArray[1..3]` or any range, it returns an array. And `array` does not have any method named `componentsSeparatedByString`. That is the reason you are getting the error.

Comment: I looped through it. Thank you!